# Can't write text into textbox in ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application.

In the codebehind for the .ascx page (which I embed as below), I attempt to write a string to a textbox in a method like this:

Code for embedding control:

Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("/RackRecable.ascx");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl);

Method to make string for inserting into textbox:

```
   string AppendDetails()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("msg" + "    " + textbox1.Text etc etc );


        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Called as (in codebehind event handler for button click):

```
            this.TextBox4.Text = AppendDetails();
```

I call it by using ATextBox.Text = AppendDetails (in the button click event handler). The textbox TextBox4 is in the designer file so I am confused why the text does not get written into this textbox (it is readonly and enabled).

When stepping through, the textbox4 control will successfully show the text I want it to display in quick watch but not in the actual page, it won't.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the textbox is readonly. Remove the readonly property before applying the text, then put it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by placing the textbox inside of the Panel.

Comment: This would be much better if you showed the code you used. Obviously, given that it is 4.5 years later, that may not be easy to do at this point.